Script send text to Telegram and Trigger Every Minutes
I have been searching for this for a while now.
I have a sheet that get data from another sheet through importrange.
What I need to achieve is to send a text to the telegram group that a new row has been added.
I found out from internet: No events are triggered when a formula result changes, so you will have to find another way to run the script. One option would be to run it periodically through a time-driven trigger. To find whether a value in the Status column has changed, the script would have to somehow recall the previous values in that column so that it can compare the previous and current values.
sample
Let's describe my goal. I have data in range A:E for send to telegram and range F:F for conditional. When I run the script, conditional look through F2:F If cell F2 value ='sent' will be ignored, then F3, F4 = blank, so data in rows 3 and 4 will be sent to telegram then in cell F3 and F4 set value 'sent'. After I have new data in rows 5 and more, when the script runs again, it will send data in rows 5 and more because rows 3 and 4 already set value ='sent'.
Last, I need a setup trigger that runs every minute to this function.
Thank you for your help.

Please show us your attempt

Send Telegram message when a new record is added:
This script effectively checks if a new row is added to your sheet then send the values of these new rows to Telegram. This also uses a telegram bot that need to be a member of the group where the message will be send.
Learn how to make a bot here: Create Telegram Bot
You will also need to set-up a time-drive trigger so that you can check if a new row is added.
Set-Up script
This app script project also needs to be bound to your spreadsheet to do this, follow these steps:
From your spreadsheet file>Extensions>Apps Script. From the editor window that opens, paste the given code
Script
var botSecret = "<use-bot-secret>";
var chatId = "<use-chat-id>";

function sendTelegramMessage(message) {
  var url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + botSecret + "/sendMessage";
  var payload = {
    chat_id: chatId,
    text: message,
    parse_mode: "Markdown"  // You can use HTML or Markdown formatting for the message
  };

  var options = {
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}

function checkNewRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange("A2:F" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][5] === "" || data[i][5] === undefined) {
      var message = createMessage(data[i]);

      sendTelegramMessage(message);

      sheet.getRange(i + 2, 6).setValue("Sent");  // Set "Sent" in column F
    }
  }
}

function createMessage(rowData) {
  return "New Record:\n" +
    "Row A: " + rowData[0] + "\n" +
    "Row B: " + rowData[1] + "\n" +
    "Row C: " + rowData[2] + "\n" +
    "Row D: " + rowData[3] + "\n" +
    "Row E: " + rowData[4];
}

Set-up a trigger:
In the app script editor, find the Triggers button(alarm clock icon) then it will open a new window, click the add trigger button.

Next is to set-up the trigger option, select the following options:
For "Choose which function to run" choose "checkNewRows". For "Choose which deployment should run" keep it as "Head". For "Select event source" choose "Time-driven">"Minutes Time">"Every Minute".

Sample Input
This is how my sample sheet looks like, this is the sheet where the script is bound to. The sheet below, also is getting its A2:E values from a different sheet using importrange just how I understood your situation.

Sample Output

References:
Triggers
Create Telegram Bot

I have tried but I got an error:
see pic: link
As see in pic cell 'F2' had value 'sent' is my manually input so when I run the script, data in rows 3 and rows 4 should be sent to telegram but it sent undefined instead.
Sorry for my poor explanation.

@Seyha TENG Thank you for responding. Please edit your post and provide your sample sheet as I believe we are varying in inputs

@Seyha TENG An actual sheet would be more helpful rather than an image, if you could share your current code, that would help a lot as well.

That's all your code.
Sample link

@Seyha TENG Thank you for responding, you should be running the function called "checkNewRows" I see that you assigned the function "sendTelegramMessage" instead

My bad, after testing again, everything working as expect.
Thank you so much.

@Seyha TENG Thank you for responding. If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer
